# Apply filter in the URL power Bi

Tags: url, filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to apply filter on a power BI report in the URL

```
_58909_87f86c04?rs:embed=true?filter=V_REPL_CE10010_C3/BUKRS eq '9036'
```

I used this code , but its not filtering.The table is inside a schema(oracle database). Should i include even the schema name?Or is there anything wrong in the code? or is there any other way to solve this

```
table name:V_REPL_CE10010_C3
col name:BUKRS(The column type is text)

_58909_87f86c04?rs:embed=true?filter=V_REPL_CE10010_C3/BUKRS eq '9036'

_58909_87f86c04?rs:embed=true?filter=V_REPL_CE10010_C3/BUKRS eq '9036'
```

Answer (score 0):

On which URL you are trying to append the filter? Considering `rs:embed=true` it looks like you are working with Power BI Report Server on-premise, but you didn't tagged this in your question.

The "table name" that you are passing in the URL filter is the name of the table in Power BI's model, so no, you should not prefix it with schema name. So check in your model, is the table name really `V_REPL_CE10010_C3` (table name in the model can be different than the table name in the database, e.g. it can be something like `Query1` for example). If the table name or column name are not correct, but in general the URL filtering works, you should see a message that the filter is invalid:

[image]

If you don't see such message, and you don't see the filter passed in the URL, then URL filtering is not supported with the URL kind that you are using ([e.g. URL acquired from Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters#considerations-and-troubleshooting)).